# Represent a table, two dimensional array or dictionary

Tags: dictionary, matrix, multidimensional-array

want to create a kind of table data structure, but I can not really figure out what is the best way. Currently I am thinking about two ways: Just a simple two dimensional array: MyClass[][] array; Or a Dictionary;

The only thing that bothers me about the two dimensional array is that I have to have unused "cells" in the array. Ex. If I got 5 columns but the second and the third are empty in the array I would have:

```
MyClass[][] array = { MyClass(x), MyClass(), MyClass(), MyClass(y), MyClass(z) }
```

And with the dictionary I would have something more like:

```
Dictionary<Point, MyClass> dic = new Dictionary<Point, MyClass>() {
     { Point(0,0), MyClass(x) },
     { Point(0,3), MyClass(y) },
     { Point(0,4), MyClass(z) },

}
```

I do not know which of both will be better practice at this case. No particular language, used C# for the ex. Seems like the dictionary thing will be better in long term. The goal is to easily and fast manage the table /insert, update, delete/ at any position : ]

EDIT:
What will be better to use and why? The two dimensional array thing, or the dictionary? Which will be faster, with less needed memory and other stuff if it comes to your mind. Which one of the two (there might be even better solution, if so feel free to tell me) do you recommend and why?

Comment: You need to formulate a clear question because I can’t spot one.

Comment: I got it updated, sorry for not be clear about that and thank you for the fast answer : ]